# Retrieve data in input text

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using echo json_encode($data); to send an array back to jquery ajax. I want to get data from json and retrieve it on input text and I got this error like: The URI you submitted has disallowed characters. I don't know on how to pass data in model. Btw, I'm using codeigniter.

Once I click the edit button, a modal will appear. Please, help me guys!!

**Button**

```
<a onclick="edit_content_by_id('.$row->post_id.')" title="Edit"><span class="ti-pencil"></span>

**Model**
    public function GetContentById($id) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cms_posts_tbl cpt')->
    join('cms_contents_tbl cct', 'cct.post_id = cpt.post_id')->
    join('cms_category_tbl ccat', 'ccat.post_category_id = cpt.post_category')->
    where('post_id', $id)->get();   

    foreach($query as $row) {
        $data = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}

**jQuery/AJAX**
function edit_content_by_id(id) {
    var data = { content_id : id };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:81/ci_sample/model/GetContentById('+ id +')',
        data: data, dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success:function(data) {
            $('#modal_content').modal('show');
            $('#modal_content').find($('post_title')).val(data.post_title);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you add brackets () for the url. It is a completely malformed url  'http://localhost:81/ci_sample/model/GetContentById('+ id +')',

Comment: What will be the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call a model function on ajax call. First you have to create a controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class myController extends CI_Controller {
  public function fetchData() {
    $content_id =  $_POST['content_id '];
    if($content_id){
    /*
      Model_Name = > Name of the model that have GetContentById().
      Assume that Model_Name => Content_Loader 
    */
    //$this->load->model(Model_Name);
      $this->load->model('Content_Loader');
      $data = $this->Content_Loader->GetContentById($content_id);
    }
    echo json_encode ($data); 
  }
}
```

Change the GetContentById function like this :

```
public function GetContentById($id) {
  $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cms_posts_tbl cpt')->
  join('cms_contents_tbl cct', 'cct.post_id = cpt.post_id')->
  join('cms_category_tbl ccat', 'ccat.post_category_id = cpt.post_category')->
  where('post_id', $id)->get();   

  foreach($query as $row) {
      $data = $row;
  }

  return $data;
}
```

And finally your ajax call  will be like this:

```
**jQuery/AJAX**
function edit_content_by_id(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:81/ci_sample/mycontroller/fetchData',
        data: { content_id : id }, dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success:function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             var response_data = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#modal_content').modal('show');
            $('#modal_content').find('.post_title').val(response_data .post_title);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I got a notice. Undefined index content_id.

Comment: Its working but I got a null response and there's no text in input text.

Comment: Do you got any response from ajax ? Check your networks response tab. If so i have done a few more edits on ajax section, i assume that `post_title` is text field class if not please change it to the correct selector

Comment: Yes, I got response from ajax. I got null value.

Comment: <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title" class="form-control">

Comment: can you post the response here ?

Comment: Response from console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post_title' of null

Comment: Join the below chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178500/discussion-between-midhun1993-and-j-wujeck).

Comment: I joined the chat.